# How to populate a listbox/combobox in email

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to populate the value of a multi selected field in an email. It works like this; there is a form and one of the category field there can select multiple values from the list of tools on that field then, when submitted, the form it will generate an email. When the email is generated the value selected from the multi selected field (tools Listbox) didn't show up at the email.

I hope you could help me generate the multi selected listbox in email.

Note: At the Properties Tools- Tools Listbox, the setting for multiselect: 2-fmMultiSelectExtended and Rowsource: Tools (Tools is the name range in where the list of tools is located)

This codes allows the user to select multiple items in the Tools Listbox upon clicking:

```
 Private Sub Tools_Click()
    Tools.selected
 End Sub
```

This codes allows to populate the value of tools listbox in generated email:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.Tools
        For x = 0 To Me.Tools.ListCount - 1
           If Me.Tools.Selected(x) Then
            Stop
           End If
        Next x
    End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't UserForm_Initialize() just cycling through each tool and then exiting once it finds one that has been selected, it doesn't actually do anything does it?

Comment: What I need is to populate the value of selected items from the listbox to the email.

Comment: Looks like you need to have some logic where you've currently got 'Stop' to populate a string, array or list with the information from Me.Tools.Selected(x) then.